# Apache reverse proxy with Tomcat and Session id issue

Tags: tomcat, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, reverse-proxy

I am having a issue with cookie path redirection in an environment with Apache as the reverse proxy and tomcat.

I am able to login to the application  and use it just fine when I access it on 8080. `http://example.com:8080/abc/`

If I access the same application on 80 like `http://demo.example.com`
I get to the login page and I can login. After login. I click on the various links in the application and it redirects me to the LOGIN page again. So I added the Proxy reverse cookie path as shown below in my config. Now after login and when I click on any of the application links. I get

> This webpage has a redirect loop

After I login.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName demo.example.com

    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteRule ^abc$ abc/ [R]

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /abc/resources http://example.com:8080/abc/resources/

    ProxyPassReverse /abc/resources http://example.com:8080/abc/resources/


    ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/abc/

    ProxyPassReverse /  http://example.com:8080/abc/

    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain example.com demo.example.com

    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /abc /

    <Location />
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Any help is highly appreciated.